# Do declined separable verbs in subordinate clauses ever not separate?

Tags: conjugation

There are often verbs which are both separable and inseparable at the same time (often with prefixes like *über*). One verb conjugator gives a separate [conjugation of *beigeben*](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/beigeben:V:haben) listing it as inseparable for subordinate clauses and separable in main clauses. Is this a rule I haven't encountered yet? Scanning google did not offer [an explanation](https://www.vistawide.com/german/grammar/german_verbs03.htm) based on my [search guesses](https://www.google.com.mx/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1MSNA_enUS671US671&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=separable%20and%20inseparable%20verbs%20german&*). Does that ever determine which to use when the verbs are listed as both separable and inseparable?

Comment: In my opinion (and in the opinion of most dictionaries) e.g. ***um**fahren* and *um**fah**ren* (separable and inseperable) are two different verbs that just happen to look the same. *Sie sollen den Polizisten umfahren und nicht umfahren!*

Answer (score 7):

There are cases of verbs which seem to behave sometimes as separable and sometimes as not separable. However, these variants always differ in their primary stress. Examples:

um**fah**ren = to drive around s.o.

**um**fahren = to knock s.o. down with a vehicle

über**ge**hen = to pass s.o. over (e.g. for promotion)

**ü**bergehen = to turn into (e.g. argument into violence)

In all such cases, the meaning and stress pattern determines the behaviour. The separable variant always behaves as a separable verb and vice versa.

Note that "beigeben" is not one of these ambiguous forms: it is always a separable verb. (In fact, there are no non-separable verbs with the prefix "bei-" at all.) It's just that even separable verbs exhibit separation in some but not all forms.

Answer (score 1):

> inseparable for subordinate clauses and seperable in main clauses

That's the normal behaviour of all separable verbs in main vs. sub-clauses.

Ich gab ihm etwas bei, vs Er, dem ich etwas beigab, ...